# How to add SOAP header parameters to WSDL in sequence without using a complexType definition?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, sequence

Is it possible to specify SOAP header parameters in the WSDL to be in sequence without using a complexType type definition?  Basically, I'm after the following as a request message and I'm trying to specify in the WSDL that two tags, HeaderParam1 and HeaderParam2, should be present in the header in sequence.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:m="http://test.com">
        <m:HeaderParam1>ABC</m:HeaderParam1>
        <m:HeaderParam2>DEF</m:HeaderParam2>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <m:search_Input xmlns:m="http://test.com/CustomUI">
            <m:DetailParam1>String</m:DetailParam1>
            <m:DetailParam2>String</m:DetailParam2>
        </m:search_Input>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I can't figure out how to make that specification in the WSDL that those two header parameters should be in sequence without defining them as part of a complexType definition under the SOAP header eg.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:m="http://test.com">
    <m:SubHeader>
        <m:HeaderParam1>ABC</m:HeaderParam1>
        <m:HeaderParam2>DEF</m:HeaderParam2>
    </m:SubHeader>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

Comment: Why exactly do you require that the parameters in the header be in a fixed sequence?

Comment: Not a must-have, just a nice-to-have.  Just seems strange that I can't seem to be able to do it without putting it in a complexType. Or I could just be missing something and its doable, and I just can't figure out how to do it in the type or message definitions.